# Angular Drag and Drop component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I try use this component in angular 4
https://github.com/jellyjs/angular2-file-drop

I have something like this

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FileDropDirective } from 'angular2-file-drop';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-drag-and-drop',
  template: `
    <div fileDrop
      [ngClass]="{'file-is-over': fileIsOver}"
      [options]="options"
      (fileOver)="fileOver($event)"
      (onFileDrop)="onFileDrop($event)">
      Drop file here
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ FileDropDirective ],
  styleUrls: ['./drag-and-drop.component.scss']
})
export class DragAndDropComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

I have error that import FileDropDirective from path has no exported member 'FileDropDirective' and also error in line directives: [ FileDropDirective ],
that Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'directives' does not exist in type 'Component'.

Comment: I find and change import { FileDropDirective } from 'angular2-file-drop'

to

import { FileDropModule } from 'angular2-file-drop'

Comment: but also have error with line in directives: [....],

Comment: I change directives to providers and it's work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change

```
import { FileDropDirective } from 'angular2-file-drop;
to
import { FileDropModule } from 'angular2-file-drop;
```

and also

```
directives to providers and working fine
```